# ajax jquery autocomplete get data from asmx

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services, asmx

I met the big one problem with jQuery autocomplete with source .asmx file
here's my code:

```
$("#enterprise_search").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Services/EnterprisePortal/wsGetFAQQuestions.asmx/GetQuestionsByWord",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "Word="+$('#enterprise_search').val(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Data recieved');
                response($.map(data.d, function () {
                    return {
                        label: item.Name + '(' + item.Value + ')',
                        value: item.Name
                    }
                }))
            },
            error: function (xhr, msg) {
                console.log('Database connect error: ' + msg);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 1,
    select: function (e, ui) {
        var result = item.Name;
        var answer = item.Value;
        $('#search-results').append('<p>' + result + ' : ' + answer + '</p>');
    },
    close: function () {
        $("#enterprise_search").val('');
    }
});
```

there is a method of c# or whatever it is (that code is not mine, just for you to take a look)

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)] //Specify return format. 
    public string GetQuestionsByWord(string Word)
    {
        //JavaScriptSerializer YourSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        //return YourSerializer.Serialize(FAQsCOL);


        Dictionary<string, string> FAQsCOL = clsFAQBLL.GetFAQCOLByWordInQuestionAnswer(Word);
        //Dictionary<string, string> ReturnLinks = FAQsCOL.ToDictionary(m => string.Format("{0}?{1}={2}", clsParameters.clsPages.ENTERPRISE_PORTAL_FAQs, clsParameters.clsQueryString.FAQ_ID, m.Key), m => m.Value);
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FAQsCOL);
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet = true)] //Specify return format.

    public string GetQuestionByQuestionId(int FAQId)
    {
        Linq.General.FAQ CurrentFAQ = clsFAQBLL.GetFAQByFAQId(FAQId);
        FAQ FAQ = new FAQ();
        if (CurrentFAQ != null)
        {
            FAQ = new FAQ(CurrentFAQ.Question, CurrentFAQ.Answer);
        }
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FAQ);
    }
```

after all of these I get in console (search for '2'):
`jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in {"5":"שאלה - 17","11":"מהו הנוהל לגבי מתמחה אשר מנהלו מסרב לחתום על טופס ההרשמה לבחינה?","20":"מהו נוהל הזכאות לגשת לבחינות התמחות?"}`

i tried to push data into array (search for '1'), that's the look: `d
:
"{"2":"שאלה 2","3":"שאלה 2","4":"שאלה 2","11":"מהו הנוהל לגבי מתמחה אשר מנהלו מסרב לחתום על טופס ההרשמה לבחינה?","20":"מהו נוהל הזכאות לגשת לבחינות התמחות?"}"`

can anyone help me with this? I've lost a lot of time for this sick thing
can't understand is it a mistake or something in webservice or in my jquery function

Comment: What does `console.log(data.d)` give you in the success method ? And you should use `'{"Word":"' + $('#enterprise_search').val() + '"}'`. Also, make sure `$('#enterprise_search').val()` doesn't contain any funky symbols like '{' which will mess up the request.

Comment: @Chintan your thing is not working, it returns error 500 (internal server error)
`console.log(data.d)` on succes (search for "1") - `{"2":"שאלה 2","3":"שאלה 2","4":"שאלה 2","11":"מהו הנוהל לגבי מתמחה אשר מנהלו מסרב לחתום על טופס ההרשמה לבחינה?","20":"מהו נוהל הזכאות לגשת לבחינות התמחות?"}`
is it possible that Hebrew messed up data I get? look at the first one - `'2':'something':'11'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And again after couple of hours mind**ng gives me an answer by myself:

`var searchValue = JSON.stringify($('#enterprise_search').val());`

`data: {Word:searchValue},`

```
success: function (datas) {
            console.log('Data recieved: ' + datas.d);
            var data = JSON.parse(datas.d);
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                $('#search-results').append('p' + index + ': ' + value + '</p>');
            });
        }
```

hope helps someone, cause I'm not the best on this thing, but shall be ;)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
data: "Word="+$('#enterprise_search').val(),
```

with

```
data: {"Word": $('#enterprise_search').val() },
```

Comment: now 'get' or 'post' returns `500 (Internal Server Error)` :(